# Limit search results to exact match

Tags: wp-query, customization

I have a problem showing results in Wordpress with `WP_Query`. Problem is simple but as far I'm not programer I wound it difficult.

So, I have custom field with values like `1-1-1-1` and `2-1-1-1-1` for example. And when I search for example `1-1-1-1` it gives me also second result and thats what I dont want to. I only want exact match to show in my search results. Can anybody help me out?

code:

```
    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        global $wp_query;

        $query = new WP_Query( 'meta_key=wpcf-resitevtags' );
        $query = $wp_query->query;
        if (!is_array($query)) parse_str($query, $query); 
        $custom_query = new WP_Query(array_merge($query, array('posts_per_page' => $gantry->get('search-count'), 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-resitevtags', 'posts_per_page' => 22,  'paged' => $paged)));
         ?>

        <?php if($custom_query->have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php if($gantry->get('search-page-title')) : 

        ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php

        //$title    = strip_tags(get_the_title());
        $content    = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(get_the_content(false)));
        $excerpt    = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(get_the_excerpt()));
        $keys       = explode(" ",$s);
        //$title    = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<span class="search-excerpt">\0</span>', $title);
        //$content  = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<span class="search-excerpt">\0</span>', $content);
        //$excerpt  = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<span class="search-excerpt">\0</span>', $excerpt);

        ?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using compare `LIKE` when you need `=` - post your code so we can help!

Comment: Compare Like? No. Here is my code. Here I can tell you more, that search string is coming from Flash. I edited post and add code that is showing my results.

Comment: Need to see the code relevant to your question - what's the content of `$query`?

Comment: Aha. If I understood your question content is what I've written in my post. 1-1-1-1, 2-1-1-1-1 and some common code. This code is needed if I want to show results that depends on people choice. Understood? Hope so..

Comment: I can't see anything in the code you've posted that queries custom fields - therefore I assume it's inside `$query`, so we need to see how the variable's constructed.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I'm sorry. I've pasted wrong code. My search.php has two queries, for two different forms.I gave you the other one. My fault. So, I edited code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a `meta_query` should help you.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(array(
                                    'key' => 'wpcf-resitevtags',
                                    'value' => '1-1-1-1' 
                                    'compare' => '='
                            ))
                    );
```

Comment: thx for helping. but this works only, when combination is 1-1-1-1. I added this only for example. What if answer is 2-1-1-2 and query gives me also 2-2-1-1-2 ? I want only exact result. And there are more results than 1-1-1-1.

Comment: Yes indeed, I too had put it for demonstration purpose! You have to find a way to pass those custom field values to the query

Comment: hm.. I don't get it. This code works, but it shows me too much. For example. If I would search word "cat", it would show me also pages that have word like "categories", "caterpillar", "mercator",... But I want only pages with words cat in it.

Comment: Was I misunderstood? I'm stucked and I would appreciate any Ideas.